# API Request: Not working from Android Studio

Tags: java, android, api, openweathermap

Whenever I try to an API request from the: "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London"
the code fails to fetch the data. 
However, this is working fine with other URLs. Here's the Main java file.
I've taken added the necessary permissions in and manifest file.

```
package thebestone.vicky.jsondemo;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    class GetData extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {

            String result = "";
            URL url;
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;


            try{

                url = new URL(strings[0]);
                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                InputStream in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in);

                int data = reader.read();

                while(data != -1){

                    char ch = (char) data;
                    result = result + ch;
                    data = reader.read();
                }

                return result;

            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return "Failed";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
            super.onPostExecute(s);

            Log.i("DATA FETCHED: ", s);
        }
    }

    public void onClick(View view){

        GetData task = new GetData();

        task.execute("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London");

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    }
}
```

logcat:

```
08-18 19:05:10.478 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London
08-18 19:05:10.480 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:250)
08-18 19:05:10.480 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err:     at thebestone.vicky.jsondemo.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:33)
08-18 19:05:10.480 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err:     at thebestone.vicky.jsondemo.MainActivity$GetData.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:19)
08-18 19:05:10.481 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:305)
08-18 19:05:10.481 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
08-18 19:05:10.481 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err:     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:243)
08-18 19:05:10.481 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
08-18 19:05:10.481 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err:     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
08-18 19:05:10.481 2380-4307/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo W/System.err:     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
08-18 19:05:10.481 2380-2380/thebestone.vicky.jsondemo I/DATA FETCHED:: Failed
```

Also I'm not able to figure out the error in the logcat and program.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check https://openweathermap.org/appid. It should be `http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London&APPID={YOUR_APIKEY}`

Comment: @Raghunandan Thanks, man. It worked out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you have got the same **401 Unauthorized** as me. If im not mistaken the answer from @Raghunandan should be your solution.